# XPathResult is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE' of undefined"** in some cases (not always) when run next code:

`var type = XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE;`

At the same time next code works fine for the same cases:

```
if (XPathResult)
        var type = XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE;
```

It seems error is raised by interpretator, but not in runtime. Probably the problem is related with activation of window object.

I have this workaround with check if object exists but i want to figure out what is the real problem. Any ideas?

UPD: The problem is reproducableonly in Chrome

Comment: Isn't it just that you have no result for XPath?

Comment: nope, i've tried use window.XPathResult and in this case it say that window is null. But in case of code like "if (window) var type = window.XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE;" it works

Comment: Two questions:

1. Is the DOM always completely loaded when you run the script?
2. Did you try given a full XPath path?

Comment: Can you try to post a snippet which reproduces this? As it is only happening in some cases, it is hard to suggest a solution

Comment: @FrancescoE. 1. DOM is loaded, method was executed several times before failure. 2. XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE is native constant, full path is window.XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, see previous comment

Comment: @Rhumborl I understand that "some cases" is not clear description, but unfortunately, i cannot reproduce it in plunk yet. May be some body saw such problem previously? Will add snippet if will success with it..